# vuforia multitarget, trying to get the Part that is tracked but the status is the same for each

Tags: ios, vuforia

Background:

I am new to vuforia, and looking at the sample applications for iOs the sdk version is 2.8.7 and I am not using Unity. Specifically I have been trying to modify the MultiTargets example to try to find out which Part of the MultiTarget is being tracked.

To this end I have tried to use the functions

```
TrackableResult *theTrackableResult = theMultiTargetResult->getPartResult(k);
theTrackableResult->getStatus();
Trackable *theTrackable = theTrackableResult->getTrackable();
theTrackable.getName();
```

to get the name and the status of each part of the Multipart (k is the index), having checked that the type of `TrackableResult` was a `MultiTargetResult`. This is done in the loop that iterates over the trackable results in `renderFrameQCAR`, where the models are put into the camera view.

The problem is that the status for each of the Parts is the same (3) which is the same as the `MultiTargetResult`'s status.

The name of the trackable which has the class `MultiTargetResult` is "FlakesBox" (does not specify the side that it is tracking and I do not think it can be tracking the image target on the opposite side of the box)

Questions:

- Is this the right way, and place, to get the Status from the result?
- Is there a way to correctly identify the Part of the `MultiTarget` that is being tracked?